# Call and parse a separate page

Tags: javascript

I built a Chrome extension. Part of point of the extension is to call a page, parse the page and see how certain values line up. I'm concerned that this could be done in a better way than what I have as far as performance is concerned and readability.

Any suggestions on this front?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.sfContactURL) {
    var passedContactURL = request.sfContactURL;
    console.info("Contact URL received!");
    console.info(passedContactURL);
    console.info("Requesting Page");
    httpGetAsync(passedContactURL,sender, parseFeed);
    }
  }
);

function parseFeed(incomingText, sendingTab){
console.info("Parsing the Feed");
incomingText = incomingText.slice(incomingText.search("Recruiting Admin"),incomingText.search("Body events"))
console.info(incomingText);
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[0] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("Recruiting is " + prodAdmins[0])
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[1] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("Onboarding is " + prodAdmins[1])
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[2] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("Learning is " + prodAdmins[2])
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[3] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("Performance is " + prodAdmins[3])
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[4] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("HB is " + prodAdmins[4])
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[5] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("Point is " + prodAdmins[5])
incomingText = incomingText.substr(incomingText.indexOf("title")+7)
prodAdmins[6] = checkValue(incomingText);
console.info("Connect is " + prodAdmins[6])

chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sendingTab.tab.id, {"productAdministrators": prodAdmins});
console.info("Product Administrators sent!");
}


function httpGetAsync(theUrl, tab, callback)
{
    console.info("Making HTTP Call");
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText, tab);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function checkValue(valueString){
    var pattChecked = new RegExp(/^(Checked)\s*\S*/g);
    var pattUnChecked = new RegExp(/^(Not)\s*\S*/g);
    if (pattChecked.test(valueString)){
        return true;
    } else if (pattUnChecked.test(valueString)){
        return false;
    }
}
```